# laravel create service provider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, service-provider

i make a serviceprovider and add provider in app.php but how can i use it ?

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;    
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;    
use App\Helpers\api\gg\gg;

class ApiServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function boot()
    {
    }
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(gg::class, function ()
        {
            return new gg;
        });
    }
    public function provides()
    {
        return [gg::class];
    }
}
```

gg class is in App\Helpers\api\gg folder and i want use this class everywhere like that

```
gg::isReady();
```

app.php

```
'providers' => [
        ...
        App\Providers\ApiServiceProvider::class,
        ...

    ]
```

homecontroller@index

```
public function index()
{
    //how can use this provider in there ?
    return view('pages.home');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you did `$this->app->bind()`, you've bound an instance of a class to the `IoC`. When you bind to the `IoC` you make that available throughout the entirety of the application. HOWEVER:

Your namespaces break `PSR-1` compliance. This is because you are not using `StudlyCaps`.

**BAD**: `use App\Helpers\api\gg\gg`

**GOOD**: `use App\Helpers\Api\GG\GG`.

Rename your folders/files accordingly. With that sorted, your bind function should actually change to a `singleton`. This is because you want a persistent state, not a reusable model.

```
$this->app->singleton(GG::class, function(){
    return new GG;
});
```

You also should not check `->isReady()` in every function, that's an example of an `anti-pattern`. Instead, this should be in a middleware:

```
php artisan make:middleware VerifyGGReady
```

Add this to your Kernel:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //other definitions

    'gg_ready' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyGGReady::class
];
```

Update the `handle()` function in your middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    if ($this->app->GG->isReady()) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/'); //gg is not ready
});
```

And then either initialize it in your route groups:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['gg_ready']], function(){
    //requires GG to be ready
});
```

Or directly on a route:

```
Route::get('acme', 'AcmeController@factory')->middleware('gg_ready');
```

Or use it in your controller:

```
$this->middleware('gg_ready');
```